# Get "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter" error when calling a web service method using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, asp.net-ajax

This is my aspx file code:

```
var DTO = { "'productCategoryId'": "'10'" };
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "/WebService/DsmWebServices.asmx/GetProductSubCategory",
 data: DTO,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (msg) {
  window.alert("success");
 },
 error: function (msg) {
 }
});
```

This is my web service method:

```
[WebMethod,ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public bool GetProductSubCategory(int productCategoryId)
{
 //do some stuff
 return true;
}
```

The problem is that the jQuery function fails with the following error:

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
\u0027productCategoryId\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

By using Firebug, the URL jQuery requested was

```
http://192.168.1.100:8888/WebService/DsmWebServices.asmx/GetProductSubCategory?%27productCategoryId%27=%2710%27
```

Comment: Why the extra quotes around `"'10'"`? (effectively making it not an integer....)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use "post" for the type in your ajax call.  Also, the data passed to your web service needs to be a json string.  Not a json object.  Take a look at the stringify method for the json2 library:

http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Among other error messages i received the same. Since i did ended up using post i would like to point the reader to my other answer: [Calling Webservice with Jquery causing woe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493209/calling-net-webservice-with-jquery-is-causing-woe-when-trying-to-post-data/6512404#6512404)