# asp.net webservice returning json embeded in xml...?

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, web-services

I've asp.net webservice with json returning data, when I call it, it return me data in json but embed it in xml.

[image]

What should I do on the server side to ensure that my webservice just returns json?

**My .asmx service is as below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

[WebMethod(Description = "DemoMethod to get Total.")]
public string GetTotal(string a, string b, string c)
{
    List<Hashtable> objMyclass = new List<Hashtable>();
    JSonOutPutProperties jsonProperty = new JSonOutPutProperties();
    // 
    int total = Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b) + Convert.ToInt32(c);
    jsonProperty.Properties.Add("Total", total);
    objMyclass.Add(jsonProperty.Properties);
    //
    JsonOutput objjson = new JsonOutput();
    objjson.objectcount = objMyclass.Count;
    objjson.objectname = "Total";
    objjson.objectvalues = objMyclass;
    //
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(objjson);
    return strJSON;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question. For example what is the end of the url; what kind of service (asmx, svc) are you using. Can you post a part of the method from your webservice that returns the json?

Comment: Hello threefouronesixonethree, post updated with code, have any idea what is wrong

Comment: High Deer could you solve the issue by adding the line `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`?

What is the result after you add the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be solved if you add the following line to your method:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "DemoMethod to get Total.")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetTotal(string a, string b, string c)
{
    ...
```

And you probably have to make sure that you are using [post instead of get.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx). Scott Guthrie has [another good post on json](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx)

Please take a look at the following question [how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json) or the [other links](http://forums.asp.net/p/1327142/2652827.aspx) in that post. I had [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493209/calling-net-webservice-with-jquery-is-causing-woe-when-trying-to-post-data/6512404#6512404) once.

Comment: Can you provide more information. 
Have you debugged the objjson, jsonProperty and objMyclass.

Who is calling whom: in the screenshot you have a browser open so i assume that your Service can be accessed by entering a url into the browser. What does it look like if you open it in another browser; what is the url to call the method and so on. Without more information this is fishing in the dark without a fishing rod.